# struts2 : How to bring up a pop up window

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts

I am working on a Struts 2 application .I have a JSP page  in which there is a normal html table. In one of the columns , I have a link called '**update**' . When I click on the '**update**' , a new **popup window** will open and the pop up will have many other details of the current row (which means it has to pass through some action and fetch data from database).

There is a Submit button in popup , which when clicked , must submit the edited data .

How do I create this popup in struts 2?

Should it be the same form as the parent window or a different one ?

It would be of great help , if you can give links to some tutorial . I am not able to find it in google search .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a problem related to javascript not struts2.I guess you must be using this syntax in the table definition for link `update`
.

```
<tr><a href="javascript:update('<s:proerty value="anyValueYouwantToSend"/>')">Update</a></tr>
```

where `anyValueYouwantToSend`may be some identifier value you want to send to identify the particular row
Then in Javascript

```
function update(value){
  var url="myAction?someVariable=value";
  window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, status=no,width=1400, height=870,top=0,left=0");
}
```

where `myAction` will be the action in which you are going to do your database stuff.In the action mapping of this action you need to give result to a jsp which is going to be your pop-up window.And of course popup window will have a different form to submit, however the update you perform here will be reflected in the parent window only when you refresh it.If you want to reflect these changes without refreshing the parent window you need to write some parent child javascript, which i can help you to do if you want

Comment: Hi anu , I will be glad if you can provide me references to parent/child javascript. That is exactly what I want .

Comment: Communicating from child to parent is simple, just use "window.opener" object.Take a [look here](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3.php). Communicating from parent to child is done by using the variable declared in the window open statement. "var childObj=window.open(url,options);" .Now you can use childObj to communicate with child window

Comment: Hi anu , one more doubt , When I click on Submit button in the pop up, it should submit the data , and close the popup window . How do I close the pop up window ? I am using what you have given above , not the parent child stuff.

Comment: use a simple html button not struts2 submit button and call a javascript function `onclick` of that button.Then in that function put these lines `document.yourFormName.submit();window.close();`.This will submit the form and then close your window.Feel free to ask if you have any confusion

Comment: If the above method closes the window before submitting then you can do this-submit the form and in the action class set a flag to true then in the `body onLoad` event of the child check this flag,if it is true then execute `window.close()` If you code help on this tell me