# How to display struts action message in a popup?

Tags: struts2, struts

I am new to struts 2. I want to display the action message as a popup in asp. I have a user creation form which then redirects to some page. So after the user is created I want to display a popup saying "User username is added successfully", where the username is a property  set in the action class for the form. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740494/struts2-how-to-bring-up-a-pop-up-window

Comment: asp + struts2 ? maybe Jsp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably put the username in session before returning and then access the username from session inside that popup.

Answer (score 0):

you can create hidden field in you ASP page and assign username from your action class to it and once you reached at this page just grab this hidden field value through Javascript and alert it.